Making a Github Docker package public while keeping the repo README private
I would like to make a Github docker package public, while keeping the associated repo private, including the private repo's README.
It appears that the README of the repo mentioned in the org.opencontainers.image.source Docker label is shown on the Github package page.
Is this README visible to the general public when the package is public while the repo is still private? If so, how can I avoid that?
If I unlink the repository, the README disappears, but the link is recreated when the next package version is pushed.
I don't want the README of the main repo to become visible under any circumstances, so I can't experiment without having to create a dummy repo, package etc.
